# groovy metaclass overriding properties not working

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
    A a=new A()
    add(a, "a", "a")
    add(a,"a",1)
    add(a,"a",new Date())
    a.getProperties().entrySet().forEach({ entry -> println("${entry.getKey()} ${entry.getValue()}") })
}
static void add(A a, String key, Object value) {
    if (a.hasProperty(key)) {
        a.metaClass."${key}"=value
        if (!Objects.equals(a.getProperty(key), value)) {
            System.err.println("error,key:${key},value:${value}")
        }
    } else {
        a.metaClass."${key}"=value
    }
}
static class A{

}
```

output:

```
error,key:a,value:Mon Jan 11 16:43:48 CST 2021
class class com.huya.TypeTest$A
a 1
```

`add(a,"a",new Date())`

seems not working，  i can't find any question about it.
and how is "xx.metaClass.a=1" working ,Have relevant information？

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?  And can you describe what you're trying to do?  And why it cannot be done without the metaclass?

Comment: expect: first time, a="a"
then,a=1
last, a=new Date()
but, first and second sucess, third is failure
it‘s a simple assignment

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, when you create a property on the fly, it is simply declared (`MetaBeanProperty`) and not materialised until you get/set it - after which it turns into a `CachedField`.

So assume the following which is a simplified version of your code (you can paste it right onto GroovyConsole):

```
class A {}

static void add(A a, String key, Object value) {
    a.metaClass."${key}" = value
}
```

now this works as you thought it would:

```
Date date = new Date()
A a1 = new A()
add(a1, 'x', 1)
add(a1, 'x', 'foobar')
add(a1, 'x', date)
assert a1.x == date
```

and that's because you are getting the value (materialising the declaration) only on the last line (`assert a1.x`).

Another example *(which is more like the original code you posted, ie doing `getProperty()` on the 2nd+ invocation.)* Note that `add()` does not work like the previous example, because right after the first invocation, the declared property is materialised (`assert a2.x`).

```
A a2 = new A()
add(a2, 'x', 1);         assert a2.x == 1
add(a2, 'x', 'foobar');  assert a2.x == 1
add(a2, 'x', date);      assert a2.x == 1
```

Once the property is materialised, you can simply assign values to it using the normal Groovy syntax or `setProperty` in case the name is dynamic.

```
A a3 = new A()
add(a3, 'x', 1);                   assert a3.x == 1
a3.x = 100;                        assert a3.x == 100
a3.setProperty('x', 200);          assert a3.x == 200
a3.x = date;                       assert false, 'should have thrown a GroovyCastException'
```